# Chatbot developed using django-channels, unable to save session specific chat conversation logs

Tags: session, chatbot, django-channels

I have been able to go develop multi-user chatbot [using django-channels, celery and redis] guide and examples. The problem I am facing now is that I am unable to save session(user) specific conversation logs as I am new to this. If any one could enlighten me how to save session specific conversation logs. Thanks a lot

routing.py for Main

```
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
from channels.sessions import SessionMiddlewareStack
import chat.routing

application = ProtocolTypeRouter({

    "websocket": SessionMiddlewareStack(
        URLRouter(
            chat.routing.websocket_urlpatterns
        )
    ),

})
```

routing.py for Chat

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from . import consumers

websocket_urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^ws/chat/$', consumers.ChatConsumer),
]
```

Consumers.py

```
from asgiref.sync import async_to_sync
from channels.generic.websocket import WebsocketConsumer
from django.conf import settings

class ChatConsumer(WebsocketConsumer):

    def receive(self, text_data):


        text_data_json = json.loads(text_data)
        message = text_data_json['message']
        message_parts = message.split()

        if message_parts:
            command = message_parts[0].lower()

        response_message = 'Nice to meet you!'
        self.scope["session"]["reply"] = response_message
        self.scope["session"].save()
        print(self.scope["session"]["reply"])


        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.send)(
                self.channel_name,
                {
                    'type': 'chat_message',
                    'message': response_message
                }
            )

    def chat_message(self, event):
        message = event['message']

        # Send message to WebSocket
        self.send(text_data=json.dumps({
            'message': f'[bot]: {message}'
        }))
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Without some demonstration of what you have already attempted, it is difficult for other users to know how to help you. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and refine your question.

Comment: I have embedded the code, kindly help me to know why the django_session db is not populated for the saved session reply logs. Thanks